# Paralelizar mi código que comprueba si las esferas se superponen con OpenMP

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando paralelizar un trozo de código. Lo que mi código hace es comprobar si las esferas (caracterizadas por sus coordenadas xcentro ycentro zcentro y su radio r) se superponen entre sí o no. Si se superponen, debe eliminarlas, pero como no sé eliminar una componente del vector sin liarla con los índices, simplemente hago cero su radio y no las tengo en cuenta posteriormente.

Mi problema llega cuando trato de paralelizar el código. Si no lo paralelizo funciona decemente, aunque mi código no es para nada eficiente y tarda bastante (necesito correrlo para unos 34 millones de elementos...). Y si trato de paralelizarlo, obtengo varios errores.

Por ejemplo, si trato de correr el programa exactamente de la manera en la que está escrito debajo, obtengo violación de segmentación. Si elimino toda la parte de `private(...)` no obtengo aparentemente ningún error, pero no obtengo los mismos resultados que los que obtengo al no paralelizar.

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

```cpp
vector<double> xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, r, d;
r.reserve(34000000);
d.reserve(34000000);
xcentro.reserve(34000000);
ycentro.reserve(34000000);
zcentro.reserve(34000000);
... read files and fill up xcentro ycentro zcentro r with data ...
double cero = 0.0;
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, d) shared(r)
    for (i = 0; i < r.size() - 1; i++)
    {

        //#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, xcentro, ycentro, zcentro, d) shared(r)
        for (j = i + 1; j < r.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            d[i] = (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) * (xcentro[i] - xcentro[j]) + (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) * (ycentro[i] - ycentro[j]) + (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]) * (zcentro[i] - zcentro[j]);
            if ((d[i] < ((r[i] + r[j])*(r[i]+r[j]))))
            {
                //hacer 0 el radio de la esfera j-esima
                r[j] = cero;
                    
                //hacer 0 el radio de la esfera i-esima
                r[i] = cero;
                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta todas las veces que quieras usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Alfabravo dicho y hecho. Perdona, no me había dado cuenta.

Comment: Hola. Tengo una observación: no es conveniente colocar `#pragma parallel for` más de una vez. Te recomiendo usarlo sólo en el ciclo `for` externo.

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla ¿pero como podria hacerlo para que me salga bien? porque ya he probado a ponerlo unicamente fuera y no me salen los mismos resultados que sin paralelizar

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla de hecho, al ponerlo fuera me da incluso violacion de segmentacion

Comment: Tal vez hay problemas con los tamaños de los arreglos. Verifica que tengan los mismos tamaños, y prueba cambiando el acceso con `[ ]` a acceso con `.at( )`, para diagnosticar si hay algún problema con el acceso a los arreglos.

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla Lo he comprobado ya todo y no hay ningún problema con nada. Es simplemente la parelelización lo que falla.